# how to fill color in image in particular area?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uikit

I want to fill the color in white area for Paint based application so please give me suggestion for how to do this work.[image]

Comment: Actually I done the touch and draw in my application but now i want touch and fill the color type functionality...Like, if i touch on the hand then hand color will be filled...please help me..

Comment: Is your problem resolved? if yes can you help me also by posting the correct answer....

Answer (score 1):

GPUImage is what you need there is a bunch of filters. In principle you need to point ios that it needs to change all whitecolors RGB(255.0,255.0,255.0) to some other color.